# phantomjs screenshots and ffmpeg frame missing

Tags: ffmpeg, phantomjs, capture

I have problem making video from website screenshots taken from phantomjs.

the phantomjs did not make screenshots for all frames within the same second and even not all seconds there , there is huge missing frames .

the result is high speed video playing with many jumps in video effects .

**test.js :**

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    address = 'http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html',
    duration = 5, // duration of the video, in seconds
    framerate = 24, // number of frames per second. 24 is a good value.
    counter = 0,
    width = 1024,
    height = 786;
        frame = 10001;

page.viewportSize = { width: width, height: height };

page.open(address, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: width, height: height };

            window.setInterval(function () {
                counter++;
                page.render('newtest/image'+(frame++)+'.png', { format: 'png' });
                if (counter > duration * framerate) {
                    phantom.exit();
                }
            }, 1/framerate);
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

this will create 120 image , this is correct count , but when you see the images one by one you will see many duplicate the same contents and many missing frames

**ffmpeg :**

```
fmpeg -start_number 10001 -i newtest/image%05d.png -c:v libx264 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

I know this script and ffmpeg command not perfect , because I did hundred of changes without lucky, and I lost the correct setting understanding .

an anyone guide me to fix this ?.

thank you all

Comment: anybody know please ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: This is the closest thing to an answer that I found http://sking7.github.io/articles/781385237.html